# Ipad not applying css on orientation change

Tags: html, css, ipad, ios8, media-queries

I'm having issues with iPad Safari's css and orientation change.

I tested on the iPad mini with iOS8 plugged to an iMac. The debugger of my safari on the iMac recognizes the change of padding on orientation change but it isn't applied on the screen of the ipad.
`font-size` and `padding` stay the same.

It looks like the iPad is a bit lazy with redrawing the menu when changing the orientation from landscape to portrait or the other way.

This is the DOM structure of my menu

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul id="nice-menu-1">
        <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <span>Dropdown</span>
            <ul style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
                <li><a href="/someSubLink">First Sub Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="/someOtherSubLink">Second Sub Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/someLink">First Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="/someOtherLink">Second Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's my css

```
#nice-menu-1 {
    width:100%;
}

#nice-menu-1 li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 1px 4px 0;
    padding:0;
}

#nice-menu-1 li span,
#nice-menu-1 li a {
    display:table-cell;
    cursor:pointer;
}

@media all and (min-width: 980px) and (min-device-width: 980px),
all and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    #nice-menu-1 li span,
    #nice-menu-1 li a {
        padding:4px 14px;
        font-size:12px;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 740px) and (min-device-width: 740px),
(max-device-width: 800px) and (min-width: 740px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    #nice-menu-1 li span,
    #nice-menu-1 li a {
        padding:4px 7px;
        font-size:10px;
    }
}
```

---

#### EDIT: Some screenshots from the iMac safari debugger (loaded page in landscape, changed from landscape to portrait):

The debugger shows, that the correct rule gets recognized

[image]

But the change isn't applied

[image]

Comment: I'm currently handling the error with reloading the page on orientation change, but this isn't a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

I may mix up here, but is this correct?

```
@all and (min-width: 740px) and (min-device-width: 740px),
(max-device-width: 800px) and (min-width: 740px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    #nice-menu-1 li span,
    #nice-menu-1 li a {
        padding:4px 7px;
        font-size:10px;
    }
}
```

Should may be be:

```
@media all and (min-width: 740px) and (min-device-width: 740px),
(max-device-width: 800px) and (min-width: 740px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    #nice-menu-1 li span,
    #nice-menu-1 li a {
        padding:4px 7px;
        font-size:10px;
    }
}
```

I have also seen times when adding a selector "all" versus "screen" versus nothing had made big differences. Just some says ago I had an iPhone that somehow did not recognize @media screen, just @media without any selector.

Comment: As written on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) i think my version is correct.

Comment: It says `@media mediatype and|not|only (media feature) {
    CSS-Code;
}`  not `@all`  - You have written `@all and` and not `@media all and` on the bottom media query.

Comment: ok thanks. i corrected my question, because it's a copy&paste error.

Answer (score -1):

I just use the following @media for ipad / tablet

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {.class {font-size:0.526em;}}
```

and for mobi view i just use

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {.class {font-size:0.526em;}}
```

works great ;)

Please can i get some votes i am new on stackoverflow and need some reputation... :D